# Why would I need to use passport package with jsonwebtoken for applying token based authentication on a NodeJs web API?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

passport , passport-jwt , jsonwebtoken , express-jwt ..etc

I’m confused, when to use which and which to use with which?

Answer (score 6):

I was building my own MEAN app not too long ago and ran into the same questions. This cleared it up very well.

https://jonathanmh.com/express-passport-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-beginners/

Basically, you use jsonwebtoken to generate the token. This is returned to the client who in turn sends it every time he makes a request. This is typically passed in the auth header. Passwort-jwt check this auth header and verifies it's validity. If it is invalid, it returns a 401, otherwise it populate your req.user.

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: But why would I even need passport in your example. I can just use the jwt.verify() function? Why would I need passport if I'm not using it to create JWTs and I'm verifying with the official JWT library?

Answer (score 2):

**passport-jwt:** 
In this strategy, server validates user credentials and returns encrypted user object i.e token. Client can save token using cookie, local-storage, or other mechanism. Then on every user request it validates token and proceed request.

**express-jwt:** 
You can use it as multi-tenancy purpose like,

1. Validate user credentials and encrypt data like passport-jwt. 
   https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens
2. OAuth: you can create jwt token and validate using secret key.
   https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/

Comment: Refer: http://blog.slatepeak.com/creating-a-simple-node-express-api-authentication-system-with-passport-and-jwt/